# Вывод изображения на экран

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Как вывести изображение на экран юзеру, при этом изображение должно быть поверх окон.
[image]

Comment: Всегда поверх окон или только когда окно с приложением активно?

Comment: Всегда поверх окон.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать функцию [SetWindowPos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos) с параметром `HWND_TOPMOST`.